# Changing const references

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Suppose I have a function that returns a const reference.  I cannot change this function. Also I have another class called MyClass

```
const Value& GetValue(const MyClass& m, const unsigned long i) {
    ....
    val is assigned by using m & i
    ...
    return val;
}
```

Somewhere else in the code.  I have to implement another function:

```
void NewFunction(int r, int i)
{
    MyClass a = GetClass();
    MyClass b = GetClass();
    MyClass c = GetClass();

    ...
    Above a, b, and c are modified differently
    ....

    const Value& cv;
    if (r==1)
        cv = GetValue(a,i);
    else if (r==2)
        cv = GetValue(b,i);
    else
        cv = GetValue(c,i);

    ...
}
```

First "const Value& cv;" needs to be assigned at declaration but i don't know what the assignment will be at declaration until i go through the conditional if-else.  Second "GetValue" returns a const so I don't know how to handle that and if i can safely change "cv" later

I cannot change the templates of the functions.

Do I have to resort to pointers or is there another elegant way to handle this?

Edit:
To add to the complexity, Value is an abstract class so I can't do

```
Value cv;
```

because the compiler rightly complains "object of abstract class is not allowed"

Comment: Does `cv` have to be const?

Comment: Anytime I have a switch with breaks or an if-chain that assigns a value, moving that to a separate function has pretty much always made my code better.

Comment: *"if i can safely change 'cv' later"* -- change `cv` so that it refers to another object (known as "reseating"), or change the `const` object that `GetValue()` says you are not allowed to change? A reference that supports reseating is called a "pointer". Violating the `GetValue()` interface is almost certainly undefined behavior.

Comment: Variable naming was my mistake. Corrected now

Comment: @mts Ok good. Doesn't any of the answers answer your question? I still wonder why `GetValue` is not a member function in `MyClass` though.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not the prettiest, you could use nested ternaries:

```
const Value& cv = (r == 1) ? GetValue(a, i)
    : (r == 2) ? GetValue(b, i)
    : GetValue(c, i)
```

You could also do something like:

```
MyClass obj_to_pass;
if (r==1)
    obj_to_pass = a;
else if (r==2)
    obj_to_pass = b;
else
    obj_to_pass = c;


const Value& cv = GetValue(obj_to_pass, i);
```

Comment: The ternary solution is fine but the other copies the object which may be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Value& NewFunctionHelper(int r, const unsigned long i, const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b, const MyClass& c) {
    if (r==1)
        return GetValue(a,i);
    else if (r==2)
        return GetValue(b,i);
    else
        return GetValue(c,i);
}
```

And then in your normal method:

```
Above a, b, and c are modified differently
....
const Value& cv = NewFunctionHelper(a, i, a, b, c);
```

Anytime I have a switch with breaks or an if-chain that assigns a value, moving that to a separate function has pretty much always made my code better.